# NSMutableRequest array and dictionary in HTTPBody, server respond

Tags: php, ios, json, xcode, nsmutableurlrequest

Struggling to figure this out.  Saw many examples, not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Need some fresh eyes.  I have an array and a dictionary which I'm trying to send through HTTPBody, then return either one, just to see it it's working.  Here's what I have:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dictofcorners=%@&arrayofids=%@", dict, _idKeys];
NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length];
[request setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]);
    }
}];
```

Server side I just want to send back either the array or dictionary.  The response is 200, data is null.  How do I handle the data server-side?  Or is there something different I should do to serialize the array and dictionary before I send the request?

```
<?php
    $dictofcorners = json_decode($_REQUEST['dictofcorners']);
    echo json_encode($dictofcorners);
    //$arrayofids = json_decode($_REQUEST['arrayofids']);
    //echo json_encode($arrayofids);
?>
```

ANSWER BELOW!

Comment: still unclear, you want to deal with response or send some data to server?

Comment: I want to run a query on the server based on the array and dictionary and return a response

Comment: seems you have resolved the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

How I got it to work...apparently:

```
NSMutableDictionary *paramDic = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[paramDic setValue:dic forKeyPath:@"dic"];
[paramDic setValue:_idKeys forKeyPath:@"array"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:paramDic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://....php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", jsonData.length];
[request setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {
//...
```

php part:

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
$obj = json_decode($input, true);
$dic = $obj['dic'];
$array = $obj['array'];
```

I don't understand the php part but it works.  Basically just needed to create one object to pass in the body...so I created a dictionary and added everything that I needed to pass.  If anyone wants to explain the php part, the php://input part, I'd be happy to hear it!